# DataGenerator TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'generator' and 'float'

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror

I created a `DataGenerator(Sequence)` class:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array(imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

This `DataGenerator` should get batches of data from two lists. `x_set` is a list of file paths to images. `y_set` is a list of the corresponding labels of this image data. `batch_x` are batches of `x_set` which is read in and divided by 255. `batch_y` are the corresponding batches of `y_set`.

After that, I fit a model by using this generator:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 128,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 128,
                    epochs = 5)
```

And got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-e56bae3d1c4b> in <module>()
      3                     steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 128,
      4                     validation_steps = num_val_samples // 128,
----> 5                     epochs = 5)

8 frames
<ipython-input-75-6e4037882cc3> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     11         batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
     12         batch_x = np.array(imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x)
---> 13         batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
     14         batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
     15         batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'generator' and 'float'
```

How do I have to modify the line `batch_x = batch_x * 1./255`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = [imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x]
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks! What I don't understand is that it is very, very slow...

Comment: it maybe because of large batch_size

Comment: Ok, but I read, the bigger the amount of data is (I have 100k training files), the bigger the batch size should be... So, I took 128. What batch size would you recommend?

Comment: 128 batch_size is just fine this slowness can be due to other factors like hardware, available RAM. You can restart your PC or this slowness is just fine.

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that my model gets trained faster on CPU than on GPU. For me, that is also really strange...